# How to destroy session when escape button is clicked in dialog in UI5?

Tags: html, calendar, sapui5

I have created a calendar in UI5 application and on calling tapOnDate method I am calling a UI5 Dialog with custom Create and reject button.

I have to manually destroy the dialog every time to work it next time. See below code:

```
 oDialog1.addButton(new sap.ui.commons.Button({text: "Create", 
      style: sap.ui.commons.ButtonStyle.Accept,
       press:function()
       {
           oDialog1.destroy();
           oDialog1.close();

       }
```

But when I click escape/cancel button which by default comes with a dialog and  try to select a date second time, the dialog doesn't appear and I know the reason because after clicking the close(X) button I need to destroy the dialog session, but my problem is how can I write such code?

Comment: Maybe you can try to close this using the event https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Dialog.html#event:afterClose

Answer (score 2):

A much better way is **not** to destroy and recreate the dialog every time you need it, but instead store a reference to your dialog and call that reference instead:

Create a global variable in your view to hold the dialog:

```
_oMyDialog  : null,
```

Then, the `open` and `close` event handlers can be simply this:

```
opOpenMyDialog : function() {
    if (!this._oMyDialog) {
        this._oMyDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("com.company.fragment.MyDialog", this);
        this.getView().addDependent(this._oMyDialog);
    }

    this._oMyDialog.open();
},

onCloseMyDialog : function() {
    this._oMyDialog.close();
},
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
oDialog1.addButton(new sap.ui.commons.Button({
    text: "Create",
    style: sap.ui.commons.ButtonStyle.Accept,
    press: function() {
      oDialog1.destroy();
      oDialog1.close();

    },afterClose: function() {oDialog1.destroy();}
```